# event.preventDefault() not working if link added by js

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a problem with event.preventDefault() because the event not stop.

i have two different functions. the first function is a xhrCall and show all posts and append the result to a table. in this function, i create a link with class="del" and href="#".

```
 $.each(data, function(i, data){
     $('#listMsg').append('<tr><td>' + data.id + '</td><td>' + data.msg + '</td><td><a class="del" rel="'+ data.id + '" href="#"> delete</a></td></tr>');
 });
```

my next function is to handle the delete.

```
 $(". del").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('rel')
    alert('delete + ' + id);
 });
```

If i copy a link directly into my index.php file with the same class, the code work!

unfortunately, i don't know what i missed or how to talk to links that are insert with js.

thanks a lot for help!

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: from past experience, i found out that alert() tend to break ajax response because the browser waits for your 'OK' to keep going but the response is long gone. Try it again but use console.log() instead. just a hint, been a while.

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: `$(".del").click(...)` binds click handlers only to elements that have that class *at that moment*, not elements added later. You can use a delegated handler bound to a parent element if you want it to apply to dynamically added elements. By the way, you shouldn't have a space after the dot in your selector.

Comment: [The answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42895336/2057919) is correct regarding how to delegate the event handling properly. Please note, however, that your selector should be `.del`, not `. del`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you say you were adding the link with ajax? If so you need to do it this way:

```
$("#listMsg").on("click", ".del", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('rel')
    alert('delete + ' + id);
 });
```

if Jquery is version 1.7 or older do it this way

```
$("#listMsg").delegate( ".del", "click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('rel')
    alert('delete + ' + id);
 });
```

Comment: Or OP could use `'#listMsg'` instead of `'body'`, to keep the handler a bit closer to the elements in question.

Comment: yeah. Is there an advantage to that? I always just use body because I know there will always be a body. Is your way faster?

Comment: @garek007 it's not just faster, it's also safer =))

Comment: sweet, I'll do that from now on. should I update the answer?

Comment: right of course it's faster because it doesn't have to search the entire DOM, just find the #listMsg id. duh, thanks

Comment: great! thanks a lot garek.. from now i will always use on("click") insted of click..

Comment: It's not significant at the time you bind the handler, because that occurs only once and it can find the `body` just as easily as finding the `#listMsg` element. But it's more efficient at the time click events occur, because then click events that are not within `#listMsg` element are not processed at all. (If you bind it to `body` then behind the scenes jQuery will be processing *every* click on *every* element to see if they match the `".del"` selector.)

Comment: Thanks @nnnnnn I will do it that way from now on

Comment: Cool. Of course, sometimes you have to bind to the body element because there is no lower-level container that you can use. It's not the end of the world if that happens. Just use the lowest-level static element, which may be `"body"` but usually isn't...